# How to design a business logic layer

Tags: oop, architecture, n-tier-architecture

To be perfectly clear, I do not expect a solution to this problem. A big part of figuring this out is obviously solving the problem. However, I don't have a lot of experience with well architected n-tier applications and I don't want to end up with an unruly BLL.

At the moment of writing this, our business logic is largely a intermingled ball of twine. An intergalactic mess of dependencies with the same identical business logic being replicated more than once. My focus right now is to pull the business logic out of the thing we refer to as a data access layer, so that I can define well known events that can be subscribed to. I think I want to support an event driven/reactive programming model.

My hope is that there's certain attainable goals that tell me how to design these collection of classes in a manner well suited for business logic. If there are things that differentiate a good BLL from a bad BLL I'd like to hear more about them.

As a seasoned programmer but fairly modest architect I ask my fellow community members for advice.

## Edit 1:

So the validation logic goes into the business objects, but that means that the business objects need to communicate validation error/logic back to the GUI. That get's me thinking of implementing business operations as objects rather than objects to provide a lot more metadata about the necessities of an operation. I'm not a big fan of code cloning.

Comment: Well in my answer, code is generated, though that's not strictly required.  It's just that a lot of the logic is repetitous, though organizing in such a fashion has the advantage of knowing that code changes go in the BS file (or otherwise to every DL if there was something wrong there).

Comment: Validation logic goes *everywhere* imho.

Comment: You can communicate the UI about any validation error using specialized exceptions classes defined in your business layer.

Comment: @Andres, exceptions as means of communication... Not sure about that one. They are for exception behavior, validation errors are hardly exceptional.

Comment: I wish I could upvote that more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of a broad question. Separate your DB from your business logic (horrible term) with ORM tech (NHibernate perhaps?). That let's you stay in OO land mostly (obviously) and you can mostly ignore the DB side of things from an architectural point of view.

Moving on, I find Domain Driven Design ([DDD](http://www.domaindrivendesign.org/)) to be the most successful method for breaking a complex system into manageable chunks, and although it gets no respect I genuinely find UML - especially action and class diagrams - to be critically useful in understanding and communicating system design.

General advice: Interface everything, build your unit tests from the start, and learn to recognise and separate the reusable service components that can exist as subsystems. FWIW if there's a bunch of you working on this I'd also agree on and aggressively use stylecop from the get go :)

Comment: Kind of a broad question indeed, but, is BLL really this undefined thing?

Comment: More that it's got a very large number of definitions. It's like trying to ask someone what the right car is.

Comment: But there has to be more to than that. I do understand that "it depends" but there's a reason why we pursue decoupling and layer architectures, I'm just trying to work out why and how BLL makes sense.

Comment: You're starting from the assumptiont hat it does make sense and you haven't defined what BLL is - and that's part of the problem, because different people ascribe different meanings for different reasons....

Comment: (cont'd) I realise that's a non-answer, but there isn't a correct one. FWIW, I personally believe in separation of concerns and the principle of correctness, and DDD is a way of achieving that. The reason you want decoupling and layers is because the more you do so the easier it becomes to change functionality within the system at large without creating massive burdens of development and testing *because software is never finished* and always changes. It's all about change control, which is modern development writ large.

Comment: I just wish that there was some kind of definitive answer. That way, I could get my boss (non-technical guy) to stop bugging me about it and just get on board with the whole thing. However, I have to repeat myself daily, this is important, you need to think about these things (separation of concerns and the principle of correctness is more than a belief, there enough evidence out there to support that as a claim). And I get what you are saying. I'm not that familiar with DDD though, maybe there's something there to draw new knowledge from.

Comment: Welcome to the war - management will never understand or appreciate you doing things which do not directly make them money, and if you do a good enough job they're likely to make you redundant :)

Comment: I'm not saying all managers stink, but how the hell did people without any actual knowhow get into a position to make those decisions?

Comment: Oh, check it, Dilbert http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/DilbertDailyStrip/~3/mjv5lqlbqn8/

Answer (score 2):

I have found some o fthe practices of Domain Driven Design to be excellent when it comes to splitting up complex business logic into more managable/testable chunks.

Have a look through the sample code from the following link:

http://dddpds.codeplex.com/

DDD focuses on your Domain layer or BLL if you like, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

We're just talking about this from an architecture standpoint, and what remains as the gist of it is "abstraction, abstraction, abstraction".

You could use [EBC](http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/archive/2010/07/27/event-based-components-for-easier-software-design-say-goodbye-to-the-usual-object-orientation.aspx) to design top-down and pass the interface definitions to the programmer teams. Using a methology like this (or any other visualisation technique) visualizing the dependencies prevents you from duplicating business logic anywhere in your project.

Comment: This is interesting, I did not know about EBC. Definitely worth exploring. I'm uncertain how much of it that's directly applicable, either way I can learn from it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in this thread. May give you some thoughts.

[How should my business logic interact with my data layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782325/how-should-my-business-logic-interact-with-my-data-layer/1782398#1782398)

This [guide from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ce40e4e1-9838-4c89-a197-a373b2a60df2&displaylang=en) could also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I can tell you the technique we used for a rather large database-centered application.  We had one class which managed the datalayer as you suggested which had suffix DL.  We had a program which automatically generated this source file (which was quite convenient), though it also meant if we wanted to extend functionality, you needed to derive the class since upon regeneration of the source you'd overwrite it.

We had another file end with OBJ which simply defined the actual database row handled by the datalayer.

And last but not least, with a well-formed base class there was a file ending in BS (standing for business logic) as the only file not generated automatically defining event methods such as "New" and "Save" such that by calling the base, the default action was done.  Therefore, any deviation from the norm could be handled in this file (including complete rewrites of default functionality if necessary).

You should create a single group of such files for each table and its children (or grandchildren) tables which derive from that master table.  You'll also need a factory which contains the full names of all objects so that any object can be created via reflection.  So to patch the program, you'd merely have to derive from the base functionality and update a line in the database so that the factory creates that object rather than the default.

Hope that helps, though I'll leave this a community wiki response so perhaps you can get some more feedback on this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "Edit 1" - I've encountered exactly that problem many times.  I agree with you completely: there are multiple places where the same validation must occur.

The way I've resolved it in the past is to encapsulate the validation rules somehow.  Metadata/XML, separate objects, whatever.  Just make sure it's something that can be requested from the business objects, taken somewhere else and executed there.  That way, you're writing the validation code once, and it can be executed by your business objects or UI objects, or possibly even by third-party consumers of your code.

There is one caveat: some validation rules are easy to encapsulate/transport; "last name is a required field" for example.  However, some of your validation rules may be too complex and involve far too many objects to be easily encapsulated or described in metadata: "user can include that coupon only if they aren't an employee, and the order is placed on labor day weekend, and they have between 2 and 5 items of this particular type in their cart, unless they also have these other items in their cart, but only if the color is one of our 'premiere sale' colors, except blah blah blah...." - you know how business 'logic' is!  ;)

In those cases, I usually just accept the fact that there will be some additional validation done only at the business layer, and ensure there's a way for those errors to be propagated back to the UI layer when they occur (you're going to need that communication channel anyway, to report back persistence-layer errors anyway).